# Xamarin Forms - Navigation.PopAsync() not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail, tabbedpage

I have a tab page i've set to the main page in xamarin forms:

```
 App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

MainPage is a tabbed page:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {....
```

Within the tabbedPage there is a content page, which has a button click to load a MasterDetail View:

```
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new AttendMasterPage(new AttendanceViewModel(item)));
```

This works ok, but the masterdetail view is loaded within the tabbed page. so when i use Navigation.PopAsync(); on the Detail page once finished, nothing happens.

I need the page to go back to the original content page on the tabbed control using a button idealy.

Hope this makes sense, any more info needed please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A MasterDetailPage is designed to be a root page, and using it as a
>   child page in other page types could result in unexpected and
>   inconsistent behavior. In addition, it's recommended that the master
>   page of a MasterDetailPage should always be a ContentPage instance,
>   and that the detail page should only be populated with TabbedPage,
>   NavigationPage, and ContentPage instances. This will help to ensure a
>   consistent user experience across all platforms.

Source: [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#creating-a-masterdetailpage)

Please get familiar with the official documentation in order to prevent such problems.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Whats the best way to load it as a root page? something like App.Current.MainPage? is there any chance i can replace the tabbed page, then replace it back once finished?

Comment: App.Current.MainPage is a root page. It all depends on your needs, hard to recommend or suggest anything without understanding the navigation flow in your app. Usually I keep the masterdetailpage as root and then build my UI on a top of it and not vice versa.